# Difference between Red Hat Fuse and JBoss Fuse

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbossfuse, fuseesb

Red hat fuse vs jboss fuse

1. What's differences between this two
2. Which one has Enterprise and Community version ?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same product. Red Hat JBoss Fuse has been renamed to Red Hat Fuse since 2018. There are no such things as Enterprise/Community editions. Red Hat Fuse can be downloaded and used for development purposes if you have a Red Hat developer account. You can also assemble and use by yourself the upstream opensource projects of which Red Hat Fuse is composed, such as [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/), [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/), [WildFly-Camel](https://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/), and [Hawtio](https://hawt.io).

Comment: thanks for response sir 
If i use it for production purposes, so i need to buy subscription 
What if i use it for production usages without any subscription ?

Comment: That should breach the license agreement. If you want to use those software without subscriptions, you should use the free, opensource projects instead of Red Hat Fuse.

Comment: I understand Although Open source projects has less features than commercials 
Example : Open source Software has no Management Console / Dashboard to analyse service, route

Comment: @TadayoshiSato Is [this](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse) the source code?

Comment: @MehdiCharife It’s just a build configuration. The source can be downloaded from the Customer Portal if you have the account.